# Referencing a field on document in Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to reference one of the fields of a document in the component.ts file.
The code below works, as long as I explicitly declare `let day = "Sunday"`.

As there is a field "day" in this.meter, I would like to be able to declare `let day = this.meter.day` instead. I know that I have to somehow subscribe to `this.meter`, but I'm lost as to how.

I've gone through all the documentation, and I'm completely overwhelmed and very confused, as this *should* be a relatively simple operation.

Thank you.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreCollectionGroup } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export interface Meter { meter: string; units: number; lastupdated: string; year: string; month: string; day: string; monthday: string}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-meter',
  templateUrl: './meter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./meter.component.scss']
})

export class MeterComponent implements OnInit {
  meterId: string;
  private meterDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Meter>;
  meter: Observable<Meter>;
  dailydata: Observable<any>;
  todayinweek: Observable<any>;
  pastweek: Observable<any>;
  day: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFirestore, private afs:AngularFirestore) {
    this.meterId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.meter = this.afs.doc<Meter>(`meters/${this.meterId}`).valueChanges();
    }

ngOnInit() {


**//let day = this.meter.day;**
let day = "Sunday";


 this.dailydata = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection('dailydata').doc(day).valueChanges();
 this.todayinweek = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection(('meterdata'), ref=> ref.where("day", "==", day).limit(10)).valueChanges();
 this.pastweek = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection(('meterdata'), ref=> ref.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(7)).valueChanges();

 }

}
```

I've tried following [Get field from Firestore document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52702157/get-field-from-firestore-document), but it didn't work for me. I received an error that "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make every variable an observable, and just let the data stream through your component :)

First you get the current id from the route param observable and with this you get the meter angularfire collection with the id.

Then from this id combined with the meter observable, you can get all the other values.

```
readonly meterDoc = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map((params) => params.get('id')),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map((id) => this.db.collection('meters').doc<Meter>(id)),
  shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
);

readonly meter = this.meterDoc.pipe(
  map((meter) => meter.valueChanges())
);

readonly docMeter = combineLatest([
  this.meterDoc,
  this.meter
]);

readonly dailydata = this.docMeter.pipe(
  switchMap(([ doc, meter ]) => doc.collection('dailydata').doc(meter.day).valueChanges())
);

readonly todayinweek = this.docMeter.pipe(
  switchMap(([ doc, meter ]) => doc.collection(
    'meterdata',
    ref => ref.where("day", "==", meter.day).limit(10)
  ).valueChanges())
);

readonly pastweek = this.meterDoc.pipe(
  switchMap((doc) => doc.collection(
    'meterdata',
    ref => ref.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(7)
  ).valueChanges())
);
```

<sub>untested code though</sub>

---

As you are reluctant to move everything to streams, even though, all the data you have is async. But luckily for you there are other options. You can use a route resolver to get the meter, and read this in your component:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MeterResolve implements Resolve<Meter> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Meter> {
    return this.db.collection('meters')
      .doc<Meter>(route.params.id)
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      );
  }
}
```

Add this to your id route:

```
{ route: 'meter/:id', component: MeterComponent, resolve: { meter: MeterResolve } }
```

You can then read this in your component:

```
readonly meterId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
readonly meter = this.route.snapshot.data.meter;
readonly meterDoc = this.db.collection('meters').doc<Meter>(this.meterId);
readonly dailydata = this.meterDoc.collection('dailydata').doc(this.meter.day).valueChanges();
readonly todayinweek = this.meterDoc.collection(
    'meterdata',
    ref => ref.where("day", "==", this.meter.day).limit(10)
  ).valueChanges();
readonly pastweek = this.meterDoc.collection(
    'meterdata',
    ref => ref.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(7)
  ).valueChanges();
```

---

If for some reason, you don't even want to use resolvers, you can also do a subscribe in your ngOnInit, and go from there.. but.. please don't :) (this is based on the code in your question)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.meter.pipe(
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(({ day }) => {
    this.dailydata = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection('dailydata').doc(day).valueChanges();
    this.todayinweek = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection(('meterdata'), ref=> ref.where("day", "==", day).limit(10)).valueChanges();
    this.pastweek = this.db.collection('meters').doc<any>(this.meterId).collection(('meterdata'), ref=> ref.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(7)).valueChanges();  
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this seems a bit overwhelming to my question which was just to be able to write the line "meter.day". Everything else works fine, and I'm questioning what the this.docMeter.pipe(switchMap... is adding to the solution.

Comment: @EzraButler your `meter.day` is coming from an observable, so you only have access to it from with inside an observable. Which means that everything that depends on this variable, needs to be an observable as well, and that's what the code above is. Every data you need as a stream, which you can access inside your template with the `async` pipe

Comment: I'm already able to access it inside my template with the `aysnc`, with no problem. I want to be able to use the field as a variable to pass in the various other calls. I need to be able to get that data a single time to use. Am I completely missing something very obvious?

Comment: @EzraButler you are :) the async pipe is also using the observable. You can however first get the value once inside your component using `subscribe`, and then create observables for the other items, but that's pretty bad practice when it comes to rxjs. Another way to get what you want, is to use a resolve in your route, which resolves the 'day' you need. But if another user changes the 'day' while you are on the same page, it will not update for you, and you will lose the realtime nature of firebase. So it's better to keep everything inside streams

Comment: so you are saying that there is absolutely no way for me to do a simple .get() using Angular and Firestore? The site I'm building is totally asynchronous and the users have nothing to do with each other, and the site data is basically updated server-side once a day. (It's an internal dashboard based on data only available once a day.) For example, I need the same "get()" functionality to pull an array of numbers to use as a dataset for a chart.

Comment: @EzraButler I'll update my answer with a couple more methods

Comment: It took me nearly a month, but I just looked at your solution again, and the way that I ultimately solved my larger issue, and it was very similar to yours. Sorry for being dense earlier.